# Не могу понять как определить сон без носимых устройств

Tags: android, google-fit

Не могу придумать способ определения сна пользователя без носимых устройств. Есть Samsung Health API, но он открывает дополнительную web view с авторизацией. По паттернам Google Fit API сон не определяется. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким? Заранее благодарю за помощь.